# Do I terminate line in bash file?: find . -type f -exec chmod 775 {} + [;]

Tags: bash

In a bash script, is the following syntactically correct?:

```
touch /home/test
find /home -type d -exec rm test {} +;
# Command following {} +;
touch foo;
```

Thank you, I know there is an abundance of information on this subject, I just need to impress this into my mind differently I suppose.

Comment: The `;`s are *valid*, but not *necessary*. BTW, you could have gotten this same answer (wrt. syntactical validity or lack thereof) from http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: First **be careful** you are potentially asking it remove all directories in `/home`. The correct command is `find /home -type d -name "test" -exec rm -r '{}' \;` Without `-name "test"` you would potentially match all directories under `/home`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think **no** directory will be removed by the code the OP presents. - `rm` will refuse to do so without `-r` option.

Comment: That is valid, but let's 'take the **be careful** route first (heaven forbid he has `alias rm='rm -r'` in his `.bashrc` -- `:)`

Comment: Essentially what I am asking is, is the + acting as a terminator, do I still have to end that command with ";" or "&&"?

Comment: They are mutually exclusive, it's an either/or. The `'+'` will build a command line similar to `xargs` the `';'` just acts as a line termination, **but it must be escaped**, so use `'\;'`. See [find(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much!